# how do you give different names to str_replace words?

Tags: php, str-replace, words

I have a piece of text, and I want to replace every word for example "car" with car and a number so: "car1", "car2", "car3" etc with PHP

I tried using str_replace(); but to no avail.

```
<?php
$text='yadadyayayay car yayayaya car aksdkjasd car car car car car car car';
$output=str_replace('car','car'.$count,$text,$count);
echo $output;
?>
```

I come to think str_replace() may not be the right approach.

Thank you very much.

Comment: There is no built-in function to do that. Write your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution

```
    $findStr = 'car';
    $str = 'yadadyayayay car yayayaya car aksdkjasd car car car car car car car';

    $count = substr_count($str, $findStr);

    $str = preg_replace("/$findStr/", "$findStr ", $str);
    for($i=1; $i <= $count; $i++)
    {
        $str = preg_replace("/$findStr\D/", $findStr . $i, $str, 1);
    }

    echo $str;
```

This will output

```
yadadyayayay car1 yayayaya car2 aksdkjasd car3 car4 car5 car6 car7 car8 car9
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace).

A pattern could be #car\d+#i

Answer (score 0):

Alright I came up with this:

```
<?php
$numberofwords=substr_count($text,'car');
for($i=1;$i<=$numberofwords;$i++)
{
    $text=preg_replace('/car/','car'.$i,$text,1);
}
?>
```

and it seems to work :) thanks all

Comment: That won't work, it will append numbers to the first occurance of `car` in the string i.e if car exists 4 times the first `car` will become `car1234` while the rest won't change at all.